# An Error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (5 ... 5) ends beyond length 0

Tags: android

I am developing my andriod app useing Android studio, I have to let the user insert a text into an EditText with a maximum length. For this aim I have employed a lengthFilter passing to it the maximum length.
Error StackInfo:

```
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1100)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:675)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:668)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:98)
    at com.newlai.test.libs.utils.TextChangedListener.onTextChanged(Unknown Source)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8206)
    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8268)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10435)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1043)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:569)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:492)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:34)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:690)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:197)
    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:184)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:295)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at com.wanjian.cockroach.a.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.wanjian.cockroach.a.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.wanjian.cockroach.a$1.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
    at com.tencent.bugly.crashreport.crash.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tencent.bugly.crashreport.crash.e.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

this is code

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                text2.setText(getString(R.string.problem_desc_num, s.length()));
            }
        });
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Post the full exception message.

Comment: Put the limit in the xml file rather than adding it programmatically !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the code

com.newlai.test.libs.utils.y$1.onTextChanged

Is editText1 a custom component?

Comment: y$1 that is class TextChangedListener implements TextWatcher